# add Column to an SQL query which shows alphabetical sequence value from another SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL query which displays result like this

```
BUNLDE_NO   QUANTITY    FROM_PIECE_NO   TO_PIECE_NO     SIZE
==========  ========    =============== ============    ====
    1          30             1              30           S
    2          30             31             60           S
    3          25             61             85           S
    4          30             86            115           S
    5          30            116            145           S
    6          25            146            170           S 
    7          30            171            200           M
    8          30            201            230           M
    9          30            231            260           M
   10          25            261            285           M
```

The result is based on Size Ratios. For example, in the above example, I have a separate table which has the Size Ratios like this

```
SIZE    Ratio
====    ======
 S        3
 M        2
```

The query will always generate number of rows as a multiple of Size Ratio. In the above example, it is multiple of 2..So 'S' Size Columns are (3 x 2) = 6 and 'M' Size Columns are (2 x 2) = 4

Now my requirement is that I want to add another column in the the first query named 'Size Group' which assigns Alphabetical ordering based on Size Ratio. For example since size ratio for 'S' is 3 so A,B,C will be created for Size 'S' and repeated accordingly in rows and ratio for 'M'
is 2 so D,E will be created for Size 'M' and repeated accordingly in rows.

The result which I want will look like this

```
BUNLDE_NO   QUANTITY    FROM_PIECE_NO   TO_PIECE_NO     SIZE    SIZE_GROUP
==========  ========    =============== ============    ====    ==========
    1          30             1              30           S         A
    2          30             31             60           S         B
    3          25             61             85           S         C
    
    4          30             86            115           S         A
    5          30            116            145           S         B
    6          25            146            170           S         C
    
    7          30            171            200           M         D
    8          30            201            230           M         E
    
    9          30            231            260           M         D
   10          25            261            285           M         E
```

Note: I have added a blank row after each ration group just to make the result understandable, it is not a requirement.

I am sorry if I have not explained the requirement in a proper manner. I have tried as much as I could, you can have any additional questions to better understanding, please feel free to ask.

Comment: You need to better explain the groups you perceive there to be in the output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Groups are created based on the Ratios based from the table ... In the above Example, Size 'S' has a ratio of 3 and 'M' has a ratio of 2..... So for Size 'S', Group A, B , C will be made and for Size 'M'  Group D, E will be made...  Each ratio number is being classed as a group...

Comment: You need to create groups of size `size_ratio` and enumerate rows inside group by letters But how do you determine that `S` rows are ranked higher (A-C), than `M` (D-E)?  What if there are three groups of `S` and two groups of `M`? What if there are other sizes?

Comment: It seems that your rows are *ordered* by `bundle_no` - is that correct? Then: What if according to this ordering, you have five rows with size `S`, then three rows with `M`, then two more with `S`, then two more with `M`? What is the desired output then?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided about sizes (only M and S)
and

- only M and S sizes
- multiples of 2 and 3 respectively
- S has priority over M

EDITED for sizes and corresponding multiples provided in *multiples* table.

It is possible to group as below:

```
  with cte as (
select  1 id    ,'S' sz from dual   union all
select  2   ,'S'    from dual   union all
select  3   ,'S'    from dual   union all
select  4   ,'S'    from dual   union all
select  5   ,'S'    from dual   union all
select  6   ,'S'    from dual   union all
select  7   ,'M'    from dual   union all
select  8   ,'M'    from dual   union all
select  9   ,'M'    from dual   union all
select  10  ,'M'    from dual   union all
select  11  ,'L'    from dual   union all
select  12  ,'L'    from dual   
),
multiples as (
  select 'M' as sz, 2 as multiple from dual
  union all select 'S' as sz, 3 as multiple from dual
union all select 'L' as sz, 1 as multiple from dual),
  multiples_priority as (
    select 
    t1.*,
    sum(multiple) over (order by sz desc) 
    - multiple as prev_multiples
    from multiples t1)
,cte2 as (
select 
t1.*,
row_number() over (partition by sz order by id) as rn
from cte  t1)
select 
t1.id,t1.sz,
chr(mod(rn-1,multiple) + prev_multiples + 65) as size_group
from cte2 t1
  left join multiples_priority t2 on t1.sz = t2.sz
  order by id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/12419)

Comment: hi @4yz, thank you for the answer but the assumptions are not always the same... This was an example to show. Sizes and their ratios can be different every time... and the multiple of rows can also be different in every case. However, the number with which size ratios are calculated to get the total number of rows will be same for all the sizes.... for example in the above case it was multiple is 2... so for Size 'S' 2 X 3 (Ratio for S) was done and for Size 'M' 2 X 2 (Ratio for M)...

Comment: Then how do you determine the priority between sizes (e.g. S over M), and what happens when all uppercase alphabet is exhausted? Also is there a separate ratios table?

Comment: the priority can be done based on the Size Alphabetical order...  priority of the size can be done either in ascending or descending...

Comment: With reference to your query that if the uppercase alphabets are exhausted... that scenario is unlikely.. as sizes values and their ratio combinations cannot be more than 26 in any case

Comment: Edited to consider details you provided